# Subplot x-axes not behaving as defined (misalignment/not sharing properly)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having some strange issue with my errorbar subplot xaxis. I have the following dataframe, which I would like to plot first from the 'hits' column to ax[0, 1], and then from the 'incorrect' column to ax[1, 1]. (I'm aware that my plot labels say 'miss' instead of 'incorrect', and this is fine - and not relevant to my question). The dataframe looks similar to 'lines_df' in this example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 5
nblocks = 4
ncons = 4

box_hits_df = pd.DataFrame({'SUBJECT': np.arange(1, n+1, 1),
                         'hit_search_in': np.random.normal(.815, .057, n),
                         'hit_search_out': np.random.normal(.918, .032, n),
                         'hit_capture_in': np.random.normal(.933, .065, n),
                         'hit_capture_out': np.random.normal(.951, .050, n)})

box_miss_df = pd.DataFrame({'SUBJECT': np.arange(1, n+1, 1),
                         'incorrect_search_in': np.random.normal(.165, .069, n),
                         'incorrect_search_out': np.random.normal(.069, .041, n),
                         'incorrect_capture_in': np.random.normal(.063, .059, n),
                         'incorrect_capture_out': np.random.normal(.045, .042, n)})


lines_df = pd.DataFrame({'BLOCK': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4],
                         'CONDITION(num)': [1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4],
                         'hit': np.random.normal(0.904, 0.091, nblocks*ncons),
                         'incorrect': np.random.normal(0.086, 0.084, nblocks*ncons),
                         'CONDITION': ['search_in', 'search_out', 'capture_in', 'capture_out']*nblocks})

### BOXPLOT AND STRIPPLOT DATA ###
hits_datacols = box_hits_df[['hit_search_in', 'hit_search_out', 'hit_capture_in', 'hit_capture_out']]
miss_datacols = box_miss_df[['incorrect_search_in', 'incorrect_search_out', 'incorrect_capture_in', 'incorrect_capture_out']]

### SERIES DATA ###
series_data = lines_df # must plot using loop, so just copy dataframe with a new name to make it more readable.

lines_df.head()

BLOCK   CONDITION   CONDITION(num)  hit incorrect
0   1   search_in   1   1.041190    0.110931
1   1   search_out  2   0.849506    0.137634
2   1   capture_in  3   0.842924    0.072298
3   1   capture_out 4   0.933436    0.065426
4   2   search_in   1   0.935998    0.104690
5   2   search_out  2   0.979213    0.039034
6   2   capture_in  3   0.873704    0.050207
7   2   capture_out 4   0.944501    0.041260
8   3   search_in   1   0.838728    0.017638
9   3   search_out  2   0.942875    0.196080
10  3   capture_in  3   0.855162    -0.022675
11  3   capture_out 4   0.701858    0.149743
12  4   search_in   1   0.969649    -0.041197
13  4   search_out  2   0.978557    -0.064566
14  4   capture_in  3   0.984815    -0.081164
15  4   capture_out 4   0.886475    0.055413
```

Here is my plotting script where the problem lies:

```
# START PLOTTING
plt.close('all')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8), dpi=175, sharex='col') #editing this sharex argument doesn't seem to help.

alphaval = .6 

# BOXPLOTS
# Boxplot defs
box_linewidth = 1 
boxprops = {'linestyle':'solid', 'linewidth':box_linewidth}
whiskerprops = {'linewidth':box_linewidth}
capprops = {'linewidth':box_linewidth}
flierprops = {'marker':'o', 'markerfacecolor':'white', 'markersize':10, 'linewidth':box_linewidth, 
              'markeredgecolor':'black', 'alpha':0}
medianprops = {'linestyle':'solid', 'linewidth':box_linewidth, 'color':'black'}
meanprops = {'linestyle':'dashed', 'linewidth':box_linewidth*2, 'color':'gray'}
meanpointprops = {'marker':'D', 'markersize':5, 'markeredgecolor':'black', 'markerfacecolor':'black'}#, 'alpha':alphaval}

# Make the boxplots
hits_box = ax[0, 0].boxplot([hits_datacols[c] for c in hits_datacols],
                            boxprops=boxprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops, capprops=capprops,
                            flierprops=flierprops, medianprops=medianprops, meanprops=meanpointprops, 
                            showmeans=True, showfliers=True)

miss_box = ax[1, 0].boxplot([miss_datacols[c] for c in miss_datacols],
                            boxprops=boxprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops, capprops=capprops,
                            flierprops=flierprops, medianprops=medianprops, meanprops=meanpointprops, 
                            showmeans=True, showfliers=True)


# STRIPPLOTS
# Stripplot Defs
marker_size = 66.6667

marker_linewidth = 2
marker_edgecolour = 'black'
strip_pos = 1.33 # position of strip relative to its associated xtick (e.g. align right of boxplot: 1.25)
strip_jitter = 0.035 # jitter the points


# Make the stripplots
for i, d in enumerate(hits_datacols):
    y=hits_datacols[d]
    x = np.random.normal(i+strip_pos, strip_jitter, len(y))

    ax[0, 0].scatter(x, y, c='blue', s=marker_size, edgecolor=marker_edgecolour, alpha=alphaval)

ax[0,0].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax[0,0].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax[0, 0].grid(linestyle='dotted')
ax[0, 0].set_xticklabels(['search_in', 'search_out', 'capture_in', 'capture_out'])
#ax[0, 0].set_xlabel('trial_type')
ax[0, 0].set_ylabel('p(hit)')
ax[0, 0].set_title('hits by condition')

for i, d in enumerate(miss_datacols):
    y=miss_datacols[d]
    x = np.random.normal(i+strip_pos, strip_jitter, len(y))
    ax[1, 0].scatter(x, y, c='red', s=marker_size, edgecolor=marker_edgecolour, alpha=alphaval)

ax[1,0].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax[1,0].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax[1, 0].grid(linestyle='dotted')
ax[1, 0].set_xticklabels(['search_in', 'search_out', 'capture_in', 'capture_out'])
ax[1, 0].set_xlabel('trial_type')
ax[1, 0].set_ylabel('p(miss)')
ax[1, 0].set_title('misses by condition')



# SERIES PLOTTING
# Plot defs
linealpha = 0.80
linestyles = ['-', '--', '-', '--']

# diverging blue-red (b)
linecolours = [(8/255,48/255,107/255, linealpha),
               (66/255,146/255,198/255, linealpha),
               (103/255,0/255,13/255, linealpha),
               (239/255,59/255,44/255, linealpha)]

for i, c in enumerate(series_data['CONDITION'].unique()):

    cseries = series_data.loc[series_data['CONDITION']==c]
    print(cseries[['BLOCK', 'CONDITION(num)', 'hit']])

    hits_series = ax[0,1].errorbar(x=cseries['BLOCK'], y=cseries['hit'],
                     color=linecolours[i], ls=linestyles[i], label=c)

    miss_series = ax[1,1].errorbar(x=cseries['BLOCK'], y=cseries['incorrect'], 
                     color=linecolours[i], ls=linestyles[i], label=c)


ax[0,1].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax[0,1].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax[1,1].spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax[1,1].spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax[0, 1].grid(linestyle='dotted')
ax[1, 1].grid(linestyle='dotted')
ax[0, 1].set_title('blockwise hits\nby trial type')
ax[1, 1].set_title('blockwise misses\nby trial type')
ax[1, 1].set_xlabel('block')
ax[0,1].legend()
# ax[0, 0].set_ylim(.5, 1.05)
# ax[0, 1].set_ylim(.5, 1.05)
# ax[1, 0].set_ylim(-0.05, 0.5)
# ax[1, 1].set_ylim(-0.05, 0.5)



plt.suptitle('Example', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

When I sharex=True in my 'plt, ax' initiation it formats correctly -- *this is exactly how I want the errorplots to look* -- but then the xaxis for the boxplots gets changed to block1 - block4, which I don't want because they are representing different information:
[image]

But when I sharex='col', it bunches all of the errorplot xlabels in the wrong position (but the boxes are now fine), like this:
[image]

I am also defining the xdata to specifically be taken from each line's 'BLOCK' column which is 1-4. So I have no idea why matplotlib is filling extra ticks between these values (i.e. 1.5, 2.5, and 3.5).

I'm sure there's something simple that I'm missing here... I have tried editing the sharex argument in the fig, ax=plt.subplots() section, and I have also tried defining some ax[r,c].set_xticklabels() but nothing seems to solve the problem.

[EDIT] updated so it should be easy to reproduce now.

Comment: As usual provide a [mcve] of the issue.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind in future. updated it now

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I'm not sure what exactly the cause of the issue is because I only ever had 4 xvalues in the first place, but the solution was simply to define the xticks:

```
ax[0,1].xaxis.set_ticks(series_data['BLOCK'].unique())
ax[1,1].xaxis.set_ticks(series_data['BLOCK'].unique())
```

Or simply:

```
nminimum_tick = 1
maximum_tick = 4
step_size = 1
ax[0,1].xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(minimum_tick, maximum_tick+1, step_size))
ax[1,1].xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(minimum_tick, maximum_tick+1, step_size))
```

I guess it was just confusing because the plot was making additional ticks between the x values.